# View full file name after selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a form where the user must select files. My question is how can I do when the user chooses a file so that you can see the file name appear fully. For example, a file with the name of toto_tata.xls, which can see the name of the file toto_tata.xls that appears after selection. I tried with size but without success.

Here is the content of my input tag below:

```
 <input id="myFile" type="file" name="myFile"class="myFile" required="true"/>
```

Comment: What do you get now?

Comment: I get the incomplete file name for example toto..ta.xls while the file name is toto_tata.xls. If the filename is incomplete, I can not see the whole name display. The advantage of seeing the full name is that the user can see an error if he chose the wrong file.

Comment: If the file name is long, I can not see the full name. But if it's short I can see. I want in any case to see the full name of the file chosen

Answer (score 0):

You should get the whole name setting up the css attribute width of the input to 100%. Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Juanito/pen/yXdbaX

```
input {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works with the css width property.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
<input type="file" id="fileUpload"><span class="show-file-name"></span>

$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
  var fileName = $(this).val().match(/[^\\]*$/)[0];
  $('.show-file-name').text(fileName);
})
```

You will get in the `span` the name of the file. The only thing left is to remove the shortened file name.

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orst4rre/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `CSS` you can add `width: 100%;` in your input.

For e.g.,

```
<input id="myFile" type="file" name="myFile"class="myFile" required="true" style="width: 100%;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a style in your input. `<input id="myFile" type="file" name="myFile"class="myFile" required="true" style="width:100%;"/>` This will work fine for me.